# Выбор элемента списка ListView правой кнопкой мыши UWP

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

Есть список, имеющий привязку к коллекции объектов ObservableCollection, а так же индекс текущего выбранного элемента типа int?:

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Contacts, Mode=TwoWay}"
    RightTapped="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectItemOnRightClick}"
    SelectedIndex="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedContact, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource fromNullableIntToIntConverter}}">
```

Метод RightTapped привязан к методу ShowMessage:

```
public async void SelectItemOnRightClick(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var s = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var d = (Contact)s.DataContext;

    await new MessageDialog($"Правый клик {d?.Id}").ShowAsync();
}
```

Данный метод я нашёл на просторах интернета для WPF. Он должен получать сам элемент списка, однако d является null.

По задумке, требуется выбор индекса выбранного элемента списка правой кнопкой мыши, так же как и левой. Какие есть варианты, каким образом можно выбирать элемент списка правой кнопкой мыши?

Comment: `var s = (ListView)sender; var d = s.SelectedItem;` - так пробовали? Почему вы смотрите контекст всего ListView, если вам нужен контекст отдельного элемента?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Не получается. Мне нужно что бы правый клик мыши вёл себя так же, как и левый, т.е. выбирал элемент из списка с последующей привязкой к SelectedIndex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для выбора элемента правой кнопкой мыши, был получен список с выбранным элементом. В свою очередь, с помощью метода коллекции привязанных объектов списка Contacts.IndexOf() был получен индекс выбранного элемента, который в свою очередь присваивается SelectedContacts привязанному к SelectedIndex.

```
public void SelectItemOnRightClick(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = (ListView)sender;
    if (((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext is Contact selectedItem)
    {
        SelectedContact = Contacts.IndexOf(selectedItem);
    }
}
```